# Having trouble with except function/ input validation

Tags: python, validation

I am working on some code for a homework assignment where I have to take the numbers in a the file, calculate the sum of them all, the average and how many lines there are. This is what I've come up with so far

```
invalidEntry= True
```

#Input validation

while (invalidEntry) :

```
try:
    
    total = 0
    lines = 0
    
    Validate= input("Please enter the name of the text file. : ")
    if Validate ==("Random.txt") :
        red= open( 'Random.txt', 'r')
        for count in red:
            strip = line.strip("\n")
            lines += 1
            average = total/200
            total = total + int(count)
            
            print("The number of lines is : ",lines)
            print ("The total sum is : " ,total)
            print("The average is :" , average
    invalidEntry= False
    
    except:
        print("This isn't a valid file!")
```

I keep getting a syntax error for the except function and I'm unsure if I have the input validation set up properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try and except should have the same indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
except Exception as err:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, fixed a few bugs for you:

```
import os
total = 0
lines = 0

# Input the file
IfValidate = False
while IfValidate == False:
    validate = input("Please enter the name of the text file: ")
    if os.path.isfile(validate) == True:
        IfValidate = True

# Open the file
f = open(validate, 'r')
# Read every line and make it a list
f = f.readlines()
for line in f:
    # Strip of \n
    strip = line.strip("\n")
    # Make the number a number
    num = int(strip)
    lines += 1
    average = total / 200
    total = total + int(num)
    
    print("The number of lines is : ", lines)
    print ("The total sum is : " , total)
    print("The average is :" , average)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now how would I keep them in a loop until they enter an entry that is valid, after which the rest of the program would execute.

Comment: Edited my code, basically I put it in a while loop and it stops when they enter an entry that is valid.

Comment: I appreciate your edit, however we aren't allowed to use break statements, teacher says it's a bad practice, which is why I had the "invalidEntry = True" part to try and form a loop, however I'm unsure of how to properly do this.

Comment: Check the newest edit now, took out the break statement

Comment: Thank you. I'd upvote your answer if I could, it really helped me out. Thank you again.

Comment: Click the tick button under the upvote/downvote button if you can. Thank you.